# Nil and boolean in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone explain the reasoning being this? Just spent 30 mins trying to figure out why my boolean method returned `nil` and found out that in Ruby:

```
2.2.1 :001 > nil && true
 => nil
2.2.1 :002 > nil && false
 => nil
```

Since `nil` is a falsey value, I would have expected the output of `nil && true` to be false. Also it seems to go against the idea that conditional operators should return a boolean value.

What is the rationale behind this?

It makes sense that the boolean operator is not commutative:

```
nil && false != false && nil
```

For others seeing this, my issue was that in rails I had a statement like:

```
def some_method?
  object.attr && object.attr > something
end
```

But when `object.attr` is nil, the function will be nil. Which is fine in most cases but when chaining boolean methods together, not so much. I just changed it to this instead:

```
def some_method?
  object.attr.present? && object.attr > something
end
```

I could do the same thing in vanilla Ruby with:

```
def some_method?
  !!object.attr && object.attr > something
end
```

Comment: Another way to look at this is that all values in Ruby are boolean. That is one of the reasons why `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` don't extend a class called `Boolean`.

Comment: @ndn or one may say "booleany"

Comment: Whats wrong in using just `object.attr == something` ?

Comment: @WandMaker your right, in my actual example, I'm using > not == which if attr is nil and something is another type you get a comparison error. I'll update

Comment: "short circuit operator"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The statement goes through the conditions in order, will stop when a falsy result is obtained and return the value of the last evaluation performed.

In contrary to `&&` which stops at a falsy value, `||` will stop at a truthy value instead.

Answer (score 4):

If first operand is falsy (`nil` or `false`), then, second operand of `&&` will not be evaluated, as `falsy && whatever` will be always `falsy`

Comment: Huh yeah ok I guess that makes sense. Really weird when you're trying to see if something's attribute is present and that value is equal to something: like ` object && object.attr == something` will be nil if object is nil

Comment: @jryancanty: I rely on this behaviour all the time. `object && object.attr == something` is shorter than `object ? object.attr == something : false`

Comment: It's not weird at all. Suppose someone said, "You've won $1,000,000 if your first name is Bob and..." or "You've won $1,000,000 if your first name is Bob or...". In the first case, you might say, "You can stop right there, because my name isn't Bob"; in the second, "You can stop right there, because my name is Bob!". Note also that in some cases an exception might be raised if the second operand were evaluated: `s.is_a? String && (s.capitalize == 'A')`.

Comment: @jryancanty  Rails users can also use `object.try(:attr) == something`

Answer (score 0):

It's good to have an understanding of variables/values "truthiness":

First, looking at Ruby's idea of true and false:

```
if true
  'is true' # => "is true"
else
  'is false' # => 
end

if false
  'is true' # => 
else
  'is false' # => "is false"
end
```

A shorter form of that `if`/`else` uses the ternary:

```
true ? true : false # => true
false ? true : false # => false
```

Continuing with that:

```
nil ? true : false # => false
0 ? true : false # => true
1 ? true : false # => true
```

Notice that `nil`, when used as a conditional acts like `false`, whereas `0` is true. (Perl treats `false` and `0` as false values in tests which is a confusing point when moving to Ruby.) `1` is true, and basically, in Ruby, only `nil` and `false` are false and everything else is true.

`!` performs a "not", reversing the truthiness of the value:

```
!true ? true : false # => false
!false ? true : false # => true
!nil ? true : false # => true
!0 ? true : false # => false
!1 ? true : false # => false
```

And `!!` "nots" the value twice, which we use as a way to quickly convert something from a non-true/false value to a true/false:

```
!!true ? true : false # => true
!!false ? true : false # => false
!!nil ? true : false # => false
!!0 ? true : false # => true
!!1 ? true : false # => true
```

Knowing how these work in Ruby makes it easier to understand other people's code as you'll see `!` and `!!` often.

All that leads back to using `&&` and `||`. Using `||` ("or"), only one side has to be `true` to return a `true` result:

```
true || true # => true
false || false # => false
true || false # => true
false || true # => true
```

With `&&` ("and") both sides have to be `true` to get a `true` result:

```
true && true # => true
false && false # => false
true && false # => false
false && true # => false
```

Don't confuse `||` and `or`, and `&&` and `and`. Both `!!` and `or` do similar things, and `&&` and `and`, however their tests will occur at different times in an expression. That's order-of-precedence and is very important to know but is a different question. You can find plenty of information about that with simple searches.

Comment: more fun: 

```
true && nil
=> nil
     ;    
false || nil
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

You list two related problems:

1. You are confused by a Boolean expression returning `nil` instead of `false`.
2. You are experiencing surprising behavior when chaining methods when one of the methods may evaluate to `nil`, `false`, or some other object that doesn't respond to the next method in the chain.

### Nil And False

In your examples, you are chaining methods that may sometimes be called on `nil`. In Ruby, nil is a falsey value (e.g. it isn't "true"), but it is *not* actually false, either. Consider:

```
nil == false
#=> false
```

They aren't even descended from the same class.

```
nil.class
#=> NilClass

false.class
#=> FalseClass
```

It is often best to think of nil as a special value meaning "undefined" or "not applicable". It may also be useful to think of nil as similar to the special database value of [null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)). Nil (like null) isn't true, false, or empty, and understanding this will help you avoid many confusing exceptions.

### Short-Circuit Evaluation

When you evaluate `nil && false` you're really evaluating two separate expressions:

```
(nil) && (false)
```

The expression `nil` is not true, and therefore short-circuits and never evaluates the expression `false`. As a result, the expression `nil && false` will *correctly* return nil rather than false. This is a source of surprise for some people, but is expected behavior for experienced Rubyists.

---

## Solutions

In addition to short-circuit expressions or post-expression conditionals such as:

```
# Send :to_s unless condition evaluates to false or nil.
object.attr.to_s if object.attr
```

you should consider the Rails Object#try method, or the Ruby 2.3.0 safe navigation operator.

### Use Object#try or Safe Navigation Operator

#### Object#try

If you're using Rails, the [Object#try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method is a common way to avoid invoking methods on nil, or other objects that don't [#respond_to?](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) the chained method. For example:

```
# Invoke #to_s without raising an exception. May return nil. 
object.attr.try(:to_s)
```

This is similar, but not exactly equivalent, to:

```
object.attr && object.attr.to_s
```

Ruby 2.3.0 [introduces the safe navigation operator](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/) (`&`) which brings similar functionality to Ruby's core.

#### The `&` Safe Navigation Operator

Ruby 2.3.0 introduced a new [safe navigation operator](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/). This appears to be an actual operator, not a method. This operator lets you chain methods as long as the expression on the left is truthy. For example:

```
object.attr&.to_s
```

Because it chains methods, and because comparison operators like `>` are really methods rather than parser tokens, you can now do things like:

```
1&.> 0
#=> true

1&.> 2
#=> false
```

Whether or not you find `object.attr&. > something` more elegant, readable, or useful than other constructs is a matter of opinion, but it's certainly an option in many cases. YMMV.