# Does Ruby have a `bool` function like Python?

Tags: python, ruby, boolean-logic

In Python I can determine the boolean value an expression evaluates to if I use the `bool` function. For example:

```
bool(1)
#=> True
```

Does such a construct exist in Ruby? I can't seem to find evidence that it does. I'm currently having to use equivalence tests to determine boolean values and was wondering if there was more a convenient way of doing this.

Comment: Which values in Ruby would you expect to evaluate to `true` and which to `false`? Ruby and Python don't agree on this question (consider not just `0`, but the empty string, array, range, etc.), so if you want something that behaves like Python you'll need to write it yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3028243/1126841 may be relevant.

Comment: I wonder if `bool(1) #=> true` implies that you would expect `bool(0) #=> false`? What is `true` or `false`? What is the expected output or other inputs? Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092232/128421 for a breakdown of how we look at Ruby truth/false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's always the classic

```
!!a
```

This also works in Javascript, C++, and (using `not` instead of `!`) Python.

Bear in mind that Ruby has different notions of truthiness than Python. In Python, a lot of "empty" objects are falsy, and custom classes can have their truthiness determined by a magic method. In Ruby, *only* `nil` and `false` are falsy, and *all* other values (including numbers, strings, lists, and any user-defined class) are truthy.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is to `1 == true` and `0 == false`, you should explicitly compare the values, such as:

```
if x == 1
  # do something
end
```

That's because, in Ruby, only `false` and `nil` are falsy. The rest evaluates to `true`.

In other words:

```
def to_bool(x)
  !!x
end

to_bool(1)          #=> true
to_bool(0)          #=> true
to_bool("0")        #=> true
to_bool("1")        #=> true
to_bool(Object.new) #=> true

to_bool(nil)        #=> false
```

Comment: Neat custom function, I’ll be sure to use it

Comment: @seeker worth looking at the `blank?` and `present?` functions provided by activesupport (in rails) as wel

Answer (score 3):

If you know which type you'll use, you could try to mimick Python's logic in Ruby.

An empty list, hash or string are truthy in Ruby, so you'll need to check if they're not empty:

```
![].empty?
# => false
![3].empty?
# => true
!"".empty?
# => false
!"foo".empty?
# => true
```

Likewise, you could check that an integer is not zero:

```
0 != 0
#=> false
1 != 0
#=> true
3.14 != 0
#=> true
```

Comment: Thanks, handy to know

Comment: There's also `zero?` / `nonzero?`

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks. It might be confusing to OP though, since `nonzero?` isn't the negation of `zero?`.